# Que signifie "non si non la" ?

Tags: littérature, ancien-français

Savez-vous ce que signifie la devise "non si non la" ajoutée par Maurice Scève à la fin de son poème au lecteur dans *Microcosme* ?[image]

Comment: Non par ici, non par là, je crois. Mais qu'est-ce qu'il veut dire par ça ...

Comment: @LukeSawczak C'est une devise que Scève a à plusieurs reprises utilisé comme signature.

Comment: @None And what might he have meant to declare by it? When one chooses a motto like *memento mori* or *omnia vincit amor*, it's clear the sort of philosophy one claims to live by. I guess after reading the epigram, one might conclude that "neither here nor there" means "all is to no end", but it's a little hard for me to connect the dots. (In English the expression means "that has nothing to do with the present discussion"; is that what it normally means in French?)

Comment: @LukeSawczak From what I've found, the motto has remained a mystery to scholars so way out of my league.

Comment: @None Fair enough! But can you confirm whether the basic expression exists in French, and if so does it mean what "neither here nor there" means in English, or does the motto sound like a novel collocation to French ears?

Comment: @LukeSawczak  I've never seen it anywhere else and I can't tell you what it means. See [for instance](https://normandie-univ.hal.science/hal-03335273/document) p. 74 « devises énigmatiques ».

Answer (score 5):

"*Non si non la*" est une des devises de Maurice Scève, qui semblent être volontairement énigmatiques.

J'ai trouvé ceci dans les notes de l'introduction [du livre](https://ia600902.us.archive.org/30/items/delieobjectdeplu00sc/delieobjectdeplu00sc.pdf) "*Délie, Object de Plus Haulte Vertu*" :

> Il semble d'ailleurs lui-même avoir pris soin de
> se dérober à notre curiosité; il n'a jamais signé ses écrits autrement que par ses initiales ou des devises énigmatiques⁵

La note dit:

> 5. Souffrir se ouffrir (*Deplourable fin de Flamete*); Souffrir non souffrir (*Délie*) ; **Non si non la** (*Microcosme*). — Les deux premières devises
> sont inspirées par Pétrarque. La dernière avait été la devise de ce Guillaume de Byssipat, seigneur de Hanaches, dont Guillaume Crétin a pleuré
> la mort:
>
>
> Le bon viconte ha pris pour son dismage
>
> A coups de traict, lances, piques et haches.
>
> Ce mot portoit : Non sinon la, hanaches.
>
> Jésus luy doint Paradis, s'il ne l'ha,
>
> Et jamais n'aille ailleurs, *non sinon là*.

On peut donc en déduire le sens de "nulle part ailleurs que là".

Answer (score -2):

Je vais dire le translation en anglais (Je parle anglais) My answer; "No here if no there".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/22600)

Comment: And why do you think this is the correct translation? It seems like you're trying to make *si* mean both *here* and *if*, but there's only one word *si* in the motto.

Answer (score -3):

"Not here not there".

Supposedly "punningly captures man's ever restless Faustian drive to be "not here not there", but rather always on the move, always elsewhere."

Spelling was fluid in French as in English in the 16th century. "si" here becomes "ci" and then "ici" in modern French. "ci" can still found in "celui-ci". "la" obviously also acquired a grave accent.

Comment: Merci d'expliquer le down-vote.

Comment: One possible reason for the down-vote  (it wasn't mine): if you quote from a source on Stackexchange, you need to provide a link to or a citation of the source. And you've missed the reason for the "punningly", which has now been explained in another answer — *non ci non là* is a homonym of *non sinon là*. I'd guess that this is the reason it's spelled *si* and not *ci*.